# Visual studio - How to require reference to dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a project with some dll references and I want to make these dlls a required reference.

Example : My project is named Main.dll and has a reference to Dep1.dll and Dep2.dll.
If someone references Main.dll, I want that the project would fail compilation unless he referenced Dep1.dll and Dep1.dll. (Like those errors "Referenced required for assembly..")

Anyone has any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to package management. If you are just deploying the dll, then all you can do at the moment is say "you also need to add a reference to {whatever}.dll". However, if you use a tool such as NuGet (you can have private / local NuGet repositories, etc; other package management tools are available), you can tell the package management tool about the dependencies, and *it will add them automatically*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't, unless you use methods / properties / constructors / etc that relate to classes in the Dep1.dll programmatically.

For example.

```
Dep1.dll   
   Dep1Class.cs

Main.dll
   References
      Dep1
   MainClass.cs

OtherComponent.dll
   References
      Main
   OtherComponentClass.cs

public class MainClass
{
   public Dep1Class Dep1Property { get; set; }
}

public class OtherComponentClass
{
   public OtherComponentClass
   {          
      var x = new MainClass();
      //// compile error, The type 'Dep1.Dep1Class' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Dep1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
      //x.Dep1Property = null;
   }
}
```